# WP7 - Drag & Drop with nested layouts

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, layout, drag-and-drop

I've got a page design as follows:

[image]

The layout is as follows:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="360" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <StackPanel x:Name="spQueuedWeapons" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding QueuedCombinations}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageName}">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <ex:MouseDragElementBehavior ConstrainToParentBounds="False" />
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </Image>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl> 
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the `MouseDragElementBehavior` seems to be visually constrained to the bounds of the `ScrollViewer`.
I want to be able to drag the green boxes to the blue drop target.

The only options I've thought of so far have been to remove the containing `ScrollViewer` or to simulate the `StackPanel` layout programmatically.
I'd rather not add manual button based scrolling or programmatic layout if possible.

Does anyone have any ideas?